# Tradingview Pine - How to access the price of a user drawn horizontal line

Tags: object, line, pine-script, price

Has anyone a solution how you can work with the price of a horizontal line object which was drawn manually on the chart?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the drawing objects (created with tools) on the chart with using pinescript.